# Inbound and Outbound traffic in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I have 3 docker images; rabbitmq, client and publisher image. Without using the docker images the three services communicate well on the default port `5672`.

Below is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  rabbitmq.messageclient:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}rabbitmqmessageclient
    ports:
      - "5672" 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: RabbitMQ.Client/Dockerfile

  rabbitmq.producer:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}rabbitmqproducer
    ports:
      - "5672"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: RabbitMQ.Producer/Dockerfile
   
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
      - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
    networks:
      - rabbitmq_go_net

networks:
  rabbitmq_go_net:
    driver: bridge
```

my **Client**

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["RabbitMQ.Client/RabbitMQ.MessageClient.csproj", "RabbitMQ.Client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "RabbitMQ.Client/RabbitMQ.MessageClient.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/RabbitMQ.Client"
RUN dotnet build "RabbitMQ.MessageClient.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RabbitMQ.MessageClient.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RabbitMQ.MessageClient.dll"]
```

my **Producer**

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["RabbitMQ.Producer/RabbitMQ.Producer.csproj", "RabbitMQ.Producer/"]
RUN dotnet restore "RabbitMQ.Producer/RabbitMQ.Producer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/RabbitMQ.Producer"
RUN dotnet build "RabbitMQ.Producer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RabbitMQ.Producer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RabbitMQ.Producer.dll"]
```

My hostname is : `localhost`
I am unable to send and receive data between the `rabbitmq.messageclient` and the `rabbitmq.producer` service. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, each container behaves like an isolated machine, `localhost` in a container refers to its local network. Communication between two containers is the same as communication between two machines with respective IP addresses. `docker-compose` creates a bridged network for all containers by default so you can use containers' name to connect to them, and Docker internally do the address translation for you.

Not sure why you create a new bridge called `rabbitmq_go_net` but connect only `rabbitmq` to it. You may delete the network or add another two container to it as well. Then in your `rabbitmq.messageclient` container, you may connect the `rabbitmq` container using `rabbitmq:5672` instead of `localhost:5672`, and so on.

References for docket compose network:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network

Answer (score 1):

If you want to communicate with services inside your compose file, you should use service name as hostname. Also, "ports" section used for mapping ports to the host machine, you don't need it to connect between services.